# git diff-tree on master branch is empty

Tags: git

When I run

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD
```

on a branch it returns filenames modified on the last commit.

But when I run the same command on the master branch it returns nothing.

Reading

```
git help diff-tree
```

has not clarified this behaviour. It says that the command compares one or several tree-ish. If only one is specified then it compares it with its parents.

On master:

```
$ git diff-tree --name-only -r HEAD
$ git diff-tree --name-only -r HEAD HEAD^
path/to/modified-file
$
```

Why running this command on the master returns nothing?

Comment: are you sure that there are changes on master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the current commit is a *merge commit* (has two or more parents), then:

```
git diff-tree --name-only -r HEAD
```

means:

```
git diff-tree --name-only -r HEAD HEAD^1 HEAD^2
```

(add more `HEAD^number` arguments if it's an octopus merge, or use the special `^@` notation to name all parents at once; the above is meant mostly for illustration).

Since this compares more than one tree, it uses a *combined diff* (or with `--stdin`, produces no diff at all by default).  As [the documentation says](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html#_diff_format_for_merges):

> Note that *combined diff* lists only files which were **modified from all parents**

(emphasis mine).  If the child (merge) commit's version of `path/to/modified-file` differs from the file in parent #1, but matches the file in parent #2, you will not see the name of the file.

Note that the `-m` flag will *split* the merge into multiple virtual commits, each with one parent, and then list the differences with that parent.  Combining this with `--no-commit-id`, however, means it will be even more difficult to tell which parent(s) have which changes with respect to the merge commit (though if some file is listed twice, and the merge commit has only two parents, you will immediately be able to tell that it is changed from both parents).